# Liberação de Software por clientes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, versionamento, svn

O sistema que desenvolvo tem vários clientes que o utilizam. Mas tenho um problema que é o seguinte: caso eu libero uma nova versão do sistema, subo ele para o *ftp*, todos os clientes que o utilizam tem acesso a essa nova versão e o sistema é atualizado.

Eu nem sei se aqui é a melhor forma, mas preciso muito descobrir uma maneira de driblar essa barreira, pois se eu fizer uma mudança no código poderia afetar até mesmo os clientes que não precisam daquela versão nova e isso iria gerar muita dor de cabeça.

Minha pergunta é a seguinte: existe alguma forma de que eu possa fazer essa liberação das versões de modo que eu escolha quais clientes irão ter acesso a aquela nova versão?

Comment: Qual controle de versão você usa?

Comment: Uso o svn cigano.

Comment: Alguma versão possui recursos exclusivos para determinado cliente? Pagos por ele, por exemplo?

Comment: @Intruso o que acontece é que dependendo do cliente, algumas mudanças feitas no código podem alterar o funcionamento do sistema que já está rodando. Sem distinção paga entre cada um. Mas alguns clientes requerem algumas funcionalidades a mais que outros.

Comment: Dê uma olhada na ferramenta Octopus Deploy (https://octopusdeploy.com) Um tutorial sobre a utilização do Octopus com o Jenkins (ferramenta de integração contínua) pode ser visto em http://www.mobiltec.com.br/blog/index.php/automatizando-o-deploy-de-aplicacoes-asp-net-com-octopus-deploy/

Comment: Mas esse Octopus suporta windows forms ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que deseja é liberar a versão por cliente, e para isto você precisa ter uma ponto em comum com o cliente, para funcionar é preciso colocar no cliente uma item que possa indicar que precisa de atualização, assim indicará a versão que o cliente tem que utilizar.

Uma ideia é antes do download do arquivo, o cliente consulta um WEBSERVICE que libera o download da versão correspondente ao cliente.

Assim você poderá ter uma versão geral das versões liberadas aos clientes, podendo assim ter o controle dos clientes quais as versões que utilizam, quais as atualizadas, e os que precisam atualizar, terá um controle mais fino sobre as versões disponíveis.

Comment: Luiz, o que acontece é que isso eu já faço. Eu queria evitar de criar muitas pastas. Ou seja, se eu tiver uns 100 clientes... Vou ter que criar 100 formas de disponibilizar. Queria uma forma mais fácil de gerenciar. Se entendi errado, me desculpe!

Comment: @ÉrikThiago, estou dando manutenção em um sistema que contem uma forma de distribuição que é controlado por um arquivo, o cliente acessa uma área e faz o download deste arquivo, se contem a informação de download é realizado e o sistema atualizado automaticamente.
Há uma tabela onde é controlado os cliente que tem direito a  atualização, e um programa que indico quais clientes tem este direito, após atualiza o arquivo texto é liberado para o cliente, isto gera muitos arquivos mas é como foi construído.

Comment: @ÉrikThiago´, continuando, estamos pensando em criar um webservice para ser consumido na carga do sistema, envia o código do cliente que consulta na base de clientes que tem direito a atualização de versão, qual a versão e assim atualizado automaticamente. O que reduz o meu número de arquivos na área do cliente que tem pouca funcionalidade. e não preciso ficar executando outro sistema para gerar arquivo e distribuir....

Comment: pô cara, agora eu entendi a ideia. A princípio eu tinha achado que no webservice iria ter várias pastas com executáveis dos clientes e que eu teria que ficar dando manutenção em todos. Realmente dessa forma de verificação por arquivo direto por webservice é uma boa escolha! Valeu ai cara, valeu mesmo!

Answer (score 2):

## Faça uma *tag* por versão

O primeiro passo é manter o código da aplicação na versão que o cliente adquiriu. A melhor maneira é congelando o código quando a versão estiver estável. No seu caso, que usa o SVN, isto pode ser feito por *tags*.

A estratégia é a seguinte:

- Quando houver desejo de estabelecer uma versão, deve ser gerado um *branch* da revisão atual do *trunk*;
- O *branch* será versão candidata. Faça o lançamento da versão e teste;
- Procure realizar correções dentro do *branch*. Reintegre quando possível ao *trunk*;
- Quando houver um bom indicativo de estabilidade, gere uma *tag* do *branch*. *Tags* não podem sofrer modificações.

Em projetos que trabalhei, era bastante comum a seguinte estrutura:

- trunk
- branches

  - v1.1-RC
  - v1.2-RC
  - v.1.2.1-RC
  - ...
- tags

  - v1.1
  - v1.2
  - v1.2.1
  - ...

Considerando ainda que você está usando ASP.NET MVC, Entity Framework e Code First, nenhum outro controle, além do número da versão em tela (que pode ser *Hard Coded*) é necessário.

Comment: Você respondeu por partes minha pergunta. Muito boa a explicação... Mas como que faço pra liberar a versão pra determinados clientes... Digo, se fiz uma tag e disponibilizei para o ftp. Como posso fazer para escolher quais clientes irão receber essa tag ?

Comment: Se você está usando FTP já está meio errado. O ASP.NET MVC deveria ser publicado por Web Deploy. Outra coisa é que você **nunca** publica o *trunk* diretamente. Você abre a *solution* na tag e publica ela. Outra sugestão é manter uma tabela de versão que registra as versões que já foram aplicadas no sistema. Aí você bola uma tela pra ver esses registros.

Comment: Eu to trabalhando no momento com windows forms. Então se usa o clickonce coloca no ftp e no cliente toda vez que ele loga, o sistema procura por atualização.